# Place a PolygonGeometry in the air in Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm trying to position a `PolygonGeometry` in the air in Cesium. In short, I'd like to use `height` to create an offset from the ground, and `extrudedHeight` to give the object a certain thickness. However when I set extrudedHeight, the height setting itself is ignored and the extrusion goes down all the way to the ground. So I can layer planes on top of each other, but no three-dimensional objects. What's the correct way to achieve this?

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
        polygonGeometry = Cesium.PolygonGeometry.fromPositions(
            positions: pos, 
            vertexFormat: Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance.VERTEX_FORMAT                
            extrudedHeight: @options.extrudedHeight,
            height:@options.height
        )

        geometryInstance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance
            geometry: polygonGeometry

        primitive = new Cesium.Primitive
            geometryInstances: [geoInstance]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what the problem is, since your example is incomplete and also seems to be using a form of data binding that I'm not familiar with.  But here's a complete example that can be copied/pasted into [Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases) so that you can compare.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;

var positions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
    -88.0, 35.0,
    -80.0, 35.0,
    -80.0, 40.0,
    -88.0, 40.0
]);

var geometryInstance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
    geometry : Cesium.PolygonGeometry.fromPositions({
        positions : positions,
        height: 1000000,
        extrudedHeight: 1500000,
        vertexFormat : Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance.VERTEX_FORMAT
    }),
    attributes: {
        color: Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(Cesium.Color.ORANGE)
    }
});

scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
    geometryInstances : geometryInstance,
    appearance : new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
        closed : true,
        translucent : false
    })
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. To clarify, I wanted to position something at height x and then extrude it for say 10 meters. I kept on setting height to x and extruded height to 10 (as well as some other weird combinations), whereas from your example I learned it's height to x and extruded height to x+10 (obvious when you know it).

Comment: That makes perfect sense; I'll make a note to clarify the documentation to be more specific about the behavior.